# Overloading operator+

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm looking for an elegant solution to the following "problem":

Consider the classes Base and Child, and the way operator+ works here:

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base(int a=0) : mValue(a) {};
    Base(const Base& rhs) : mValue(rhs.mValue) {};
    Base& operator=(const Base& rhs) {
        if (this==&rhs) return *this;
        mValue=rhs.mValue;
    }


    friend const Base operator+(Base &lhs, Base &rhs);

private:
    int mValue;
};

const Base operator+(Base &lhs, Base &rhs)
{
    Base result(lhs.mValue+rhs.mValue);
    return result;
}

class Child : public Base
{
public:
    Child(int a=0) : Base(a) {};
};

int main()
{
    Child a(2);
    Child b(5);
    Child c(a+b);  // **** This line ****
            Child d;
            d=(a+b); // **** or this other one ****

}
```

The marked lines in *main* give the error:
*cannot convert from 'const Base' to 'Child'*

I understand perfectly that the operator has been defined in the *Base* class, and returns an object of type *Base*, which can't be converted to *Child*.
One solution is overloading *operator+* for the *Child* class, but I am wondering whether there is a better, less costly method. I'm under the impression that I'm forgetting a much easier option. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, typo :) Now corrected

Comment: Why does `operator=` not return anything? Does it even compile? Also read up on the [copy-swap-idiom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom)

Comment: @andre - The asignment operator is not the problem. I have updated the question to reflect this. The problem is the same for *c* and *d*: *operator+* returns a *Base* object, not a *Child* object.

Comment: If thats the case you should only need to add the copy constructor  `Child(const Base& other) : Base(other) {...};`

Comment: Actually, that was suggested by rajenpandit a few minutes ago, but I missunderstood it. It actually works! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define a constructor `Child(Base& obj)` then `Child c=(a+b);` statement will be fine and  then you can use the base object as per your requirement.

Comment: Instead of Child(Base& obj), it should be Child(const Base& obj) : Base(obj) { };

Comment: Apologies rajenpandit, I actually made a mistake when I tried your suggestion. It works, so thank you very much!

Comment: @Bill Perkins - Thank you, that is exactly what I tried (rajenpandit omitted the *const*, but actually I left it there because it is what I need)

Answer (score 1):

There is no easier option.

Operator overloading and class hierarchies don't really like to mix. I'm personally very suspicious when a type that should be a value type (or else why are you overloading operators?) is part of a hierarchy. Can you describe your actual architecture? Does it actually make sense to overload the operator there?

Comment: The actual classes are a bit more complex than a simple wrapped int, but the principle is the same as in the example. Both base and derived classes need an *operator+*, with identical functionallity, only that in the derived class it returns a derived object.

Comment: What do these classes represent that makes them need the operator and yet puts them in an inheritance relationship?

Comment: They are matrices, the derived class is an special type of the Base class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build a child from a base without adding the appropriate constructor, there is another alternative. You can declare the casting operator in your base class, returning your `mValue` :

```
operator int() const;
```

This way, the compiler will do the job implicitly.

**PS** : Ensure const-correctness of your additive operator :

```
friend Base operator+(const Base &lhs, const Base &rhs);
```